# Multiple object locking with variable object count

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, mutex

I have an array of my own classes, with size `N`. Each instance can reference other instances in the array, and holds a list of indices in the list.

```
class A
{
    public List<int> References { get; } = new List<int>();
}

A[] a_array = new A[N];
```

I want to create a smart locking system - an array with size `N`, where in each index I hold a lock for each instance in `a_array`. Whenever I update or read an instance in `a_array` I need to lock the instance and all its references.

```
object[] locks = new object[N];

foreach (var refer in a.References)
{
    // lock locks[refer];
}
```

How do I lock multiple objects in C#, when the number of locks per instance is variable (The number of references can be different for each `A` instance)

I know I can use Mutex for this, but I want to make sure the mutex is released whenever an exception is thrown in my code.

Comment: "when I don't know in advance how many lock I need to lock" - you _do_ know - exactly 1 per `A` you need to read from or modify. So you start by acquiring a lock for the `A` you're reading the reference list from - then you acquire the corresponding lock for the reference `A`, do your modification, release the lock, and once you've done that for each reference, you can release the original lock

Comment: What you are trying to do will have as a result, most likely, to you discovering the [dining philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) the hard way.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias My references have no circles, and that is validated externally, so when implemented correctly there should be no deadlocks.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The question specifies that the object and all referenced objects are needed together inside the lock.  That's literally the problem statement.  Why do you think they can access each object or a referenced object without needing to lock on the referenced objects?  Plenty of operations will require preventing an object and numerous related objects from being changed from another thread for the duration of some critical section.  It's a common enough thing to need to do (granted often the number of related objects is known at compile time).

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I changed the question description, I know the number of locks, but it's variable. The question is how I can use the `lock () {}` structure with this kind of problem, because using `Mutex` can cause not releasing it on errors.

Comment: As a side note, the `References` property being a `List<int>` seems less robust than being a `List<A>`. If the `A` objects are not exposed to external code, you could also consider using them directly as lockers, instead of creating a dedicated locker `object` associated with each `A` instance.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Normally I would agree, but in this situation having all of the objects in an array is actually beneficial because it provides a clear total ordering of the items.  If each object has a list of the objects itself, it's possible for two objects to be in two different lists of references in different order.  While that's also possible when storing indexes, it'd be easier to spot the mistake when storing indexes.  Particularly if the objects can't be sensibly compared to each other for an order (that may not actually be a concern, but a shared array does solve that issue).

Comment: @Servy I agree in general, but the OP [has already clarified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70172499/multiple-object-locking-with-variable-object-count?noredirect=1#comment124046784_70172499) that the references have no circles, and so the order of acquiring the locks is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias There not being circules doesn't mean two objects aren't both referencing the same two other objects.  That's not a cycle (since this is a directed graph, not a bidirectional graph).  So the order is still relevant.  There being no cycles simply means that a consistent total order exists.  It doesn't mean that the items can be locked in any order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lock` is just shorthand for `Monitor.Enter` in a try/finally with a `Monitor.Exit` at the end.  You can just do that explicitly in a loop.

Providing a lambda of the critical section means that the entire lock management is tightly encapsulated, making it harder to forget to properly release locks.

```
public static void LockAll(IEnumerable<object> lockObjects, Action action)
{
    List<object> enteredLocks = new List<object>();
    try
    {
        foreach (var lockObject in lockObjects)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
            enteredLocks.Add(lockObject);
        }

        action();
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var lockObject in enteredLocks)
            Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
}
public static T LockAll<T>(IEnumerable<object> lockObjects, Func<T> func)
{
    List<object> enteredLocks = new List<object>();
    try
    {
        foreach (var lockObject in lockObjects)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
            enteredLocks.Add(lockObject);
        }

        return func();
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var lockObject in enteredLocks)
            Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
}
```

As with any situation where you lock on multiple things, you need to ensure you always lock on items in a consistent ordering to avoid deadlocks.